# Implement background subtraction in opencv java for video input from webcam?

Tags: java, opencv, webcam, background-subtraction

I want to extract foreground mask of moving human alone in a static background. How to implement this in open-CV java?

```
package com.java.opencv;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.video.BackgroundSubtractor;
import org.opencv.video.BackgroundSubtractorMOG2;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class HelloCV {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
          Mat camImage = new Mat();
          BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 backgroundSubtractorMOG=new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
            if (capture.isOpened()) {
                while (true) {
                    capture.read(camImage);


                    Mat fgMask=new Mat();
                    backgroundSubtractorMOG.apply(camImage, fgMask,0.1);

                    Mat output=new Mat();
                    camImage.copyTo(output,fgMask);

                    //displayImageOnScreen(output);
                   }
                }
    }
}
```

im getting an error at this line.

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 backgroundSubtractorMOG=new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```

> The constructor BackgroundSubtractorMOG2() is undefined

Couldn't find proper documentation for these methods

Comment: please add the code snippet you have tried till now.

Comment: What you need is absdiff() method. Read about it here: http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/index.html?org/opencv/core/Core.html

Comment: @Sri.U i have updated the code

Comment: Seems like they removed constructors in the last version, probably this should work: `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();`

Comment: @StepTNT wow that works, but how to display the output on the screen?

Comment: This is a whole new question, I suggest you to accept the answer on this one and then create a new question to get help.

Answer (score 6):

They removed constructors in the last version, use this:

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog2 = Video.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
```